# Site choice dropdown cannot be shown on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

- Ask a question, open the "Ask on which site?" dropdown menu.
- Press the back button.

Issue: the menu will disappear and you can't bring it back by tapping the arrow or the field. Only typing text or selecting another field then tapping back will return the dropdown menu.

Comment: Reproduced in app v1.0.43 on a HTC One.

Comment: Reproduced in app v1.0.82 (beta) on a Nexus 5. Also occurs when editing "Your Sites".